# Reverse every 4bits in in 32 bit int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Reverse every bits in each 4 bit, e.g:

```
0101 1011 1100 0110 becomes
1010 1101 0011 0110
```

Another:

```
1010 1100 0101 1100 becomes
0101 0011 1010 0011
```

I can think to reverse all 32 bit as below:

```
unsigned int reverseBits(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int count = sizeof(num) * 8 - 1;
    unsigned int reverse_num = num;

    num >>= 1; 
    while(num)
    {
       reverse_num <<= 1;       
       reverse_num |= num & 1;
       num >>= 1;
       count--;
    }
    reverse_num <<= count;
    return reverse_num;
}
```

But how to solve the above problem?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the first example.

Comment: I can't make any sense of your examples or your problem description. Other than that, I'm ready to help... :!

Comment: Isn't your first example completely wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: reverse every bit in every 4bit means 1100 would be 0011 then above both example is correct one, thats what i want.

Answer (score 9):

You can take the algorithm for [complete bit-reversal](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel), and delete a couple of steps, leaving you with just: (not tested)

```
x = ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555) | ((x & 0x55555555) << 1);  // swap odd/even bits
x = ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333) | ((x & 0x33333333) << 2);  // swap groups of 2
```

Obviously that assumes unsigned ints are 32 bits.

Comment: @kol that's interesting, his first example is wrong - I hope this code *didn't* get the same result

Comment: Sure, I got `1010 1101 0011 0110`

Comment: Thanks, that gives perfect ans

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Lookup-table to reverse nibbles. The `i`-th element gives the nibble-reversed version of `i`, where `i` is an unsigned byte:

```
static const unsigned char lut[] = {
  0x00, 0x08, 0x04, 0x0C, 0x02, 0x0A, 0x06, 0x0E, 
  0x01, 0x09, 0x05, 0x0D, 0x03, 0x0B, 0x07, 0x0F, 
  0x80, 0x88, 0x84, 0x8C, 0x82, 0x8A, 0x86, 0x8E, 
  0x81, 0x89, 0x85, 0x8D, 0x83, 0x8B, 0x87, 0x8F, 
  0x40, 0x48, 0x44, 0x4C, 0x42, 0x4A, 0x46, 0x4E, 
  0x41, 0x49, 0x45, 0x4D, 0x43, 0x4B, 0x47, 0x4F, 
  0xC0, 0xC8, 0xC4, 0xCC, 0xC2, 0xCA, 0xC6, 0xCE, 
  0xC1, 0xC9, 0xC5, 0xCD, 0xC3, 0xCB, 0xC7, 0xCF, 
  0x20, 0x28, 0x24, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x2A, 0x26, 0x2E, 
  0x21, 0x29, 0x25, 0x2D, 0x23, 0x2B, 0x27, 0x2F, 
  0xA0, 0xA8, 0xA4, 0xAC, 0xA2, 0xAA, 0xA6, 0xAE, 
  0xA1, 0xA9, 0xA5, 0xAD, 0xA3, 0xAB, 0xA7, 0xAF, 
  0x60, 0x68, 0x64, 0x6C, 0x62, 0x6A, 0x66, 0x6E, 
  0x61, 0x69, 0x65, 0x6D, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x67, 0x6F, 
  0xE0, 0xE8, 0xE4, 0xEC, 0xE2, 0xEA, 0xE6, 0xEE, 
  0xE1, 0xE9, 0xE5, 0xED, 0xE3, 0xEB, 0xE7, 0xEF, 
  0x10, 0x18, 0x14, 0x1C, 0x12, 0x1A, 0x16, 0x1E, 
  0x11, 0x19, 0x15, 0x1D, 0x13, 0x1B, 0x17, 0x1F, 
  0x90, 0x98, 0x94, 0x9C, 0x92, 0x9A, 0x96, 0x9E, 
  0x91, 0x99, 0x95, 0x9D, 0x93, 0x9B, 0x97, 0x9F, 
  0x50, 0x58, 0x54, 0x5C, 0x52, 0x5A, 0x56, 0x5E, 
  0x51, 0x59, 0x55, 0x5D, 0x53, 0x5B, 0x57, 0x5F, 
  0xD0, 0xD8, 0xD4, 0xDC, 0xD2, 0xDA, 0xD6, 0xDE, 
  0xD1, 0xD9, 0xD5, 0xDD, 0xD3, 0xDB, 0xD7, 0xDF, 
  0x30, 0x38, 0x34, 0x3C, 0x32, 0x3A, 0x36, 0x3E, 
  0x31, 0x39, 0x35, 0x3D, 0x33, 0x3B, 0x37, 0x3F, 
  0xB0, 0xB8, 0xB4, 0xBC, 0xB2, 0xBA, 0xB6, 0xBE, 
  0xB1, 0xB9, 0xB5, 0xBD, 0xB3, 0xBB, 0xB7, 0xBF, 
  0x70, 0x78, 0x74, 0x7C, 0x72, 0x7A, 0x76, 0x7E, 
  0x71, 0x79, 0x75, 0x7D, 0x73, 0x7B, 0x77, 0x7F, 
  0xF0, 0xF8, 0xF4, 0xFC, 0xF2, 0xFA, 0xF6, 0xFE, 
  0xF1, 0xF9, 0xF5, 0xFD, 0xF3, 0xFB, 0xF7, 0xFF
};
```

**2.** Function to reverse the nibbles. It applies the lookup-table to every byte of an unsigned 4-byte integer:

```
unsigned reverse_nibbles(unsigned i) {
  return (lut[(i & 0xFF000000) >> 24] << 24) |
         (lut[(i & 0x00FF0000) >> 16] << 16) |
         (lut[(i & 0x0000FF00) >>  8] <<  8) |
         (lut[ i & 0x000000FF       ]      );
}
```

Test results ([ideone](http://ideone.com/ZIFD6s)):

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 1011 1100 0110
0000 0000 0000 0000 1010 1101 0011 0110

0000 0000 0000 0000 1010 1100 0101 1100
0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 0011 1010 0011

1100 1010 1111 1110 1011 1010 1011 1110
0011 0101 1111 0111 1101 0101 1101 0111
```

The lookup table was pre-calculated this way ([ideone](http://ideone.com/EDLBO3)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  unsigned i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    j = ((i & 0x01) << 3) | 
        ((i & 0x02) << 1) | 
        ((i & 0x04) >> 1) | 
        ((i & 0x08) >> 3) |
        ((i & 0x10) << 3) |
        ((i & 0x20) << 1) |
        ((i & 0x40) >> 1) |
        ((i & 0x80) >> 3);
    printf("0x%02X, ", j);
    if (((i + 1) % 8) == 0)
      printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , Thats perfect solution to use the lookup table

Answer (score 0):

Use code similar to what you have for each run of 4 bits, shifting each reversed nibble into the final result.

You could have 1 version of your code extract & replace each run of 4 bits (shifting by 4 bits with each iteration), and calling a *different* version that takes a 4-bit value & reverses those 4 bits (by setting `count` to 3, I believe).

Comment: Can you elaborate more about this?

Answer (score -1):

My answer to swap every 4 bit is as below:

```
num = ((num&0F0F0F0F)<<4)|((num>>4)&0F0F0F0F);
```

Comment: this swaps the nibbles, not reverse it like you expected. For example 0x12345678 becomes 0x21436587

Comment: Then how does it answer your question?

Comment: unless you edit your answer to reverse each nibble like what your question stated, I'll keep the downvote

Comment: `0F0F0F0F` is not even a valid number in C